# Using INDEX/MATCH with Multiple Values as keyword search

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

[image: I am trying to get I4 to retrieve the Subtopic based on the text on Column G. I've used =INDEX($B$2:$B$4,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$2:$C$4,$G4)),0)) to retrieve the column H using 1 keyword. Any idea on how would it]

I am trying to get I4 to retrieve the Subtopic based on the text on Column G. I've used *=INDEX($B$2:$B$4,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$2:$C$4,$G4)),0))* to retrieve the column H using 1 keyword. Any workaround to this? I've tried the use formula as in the picture to give it attempt, but it doesnt work as intended.

Comment: `MATCH(1,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$2:$C$4,$G4))*ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$2:$D$4,$G4)),0)`

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately that does not work as intended for me at least. Where the answer at I4 should have been Wand instead of Staves.

Comment: You need to array enter it with Ctrl-shift-enter

Comment: My bad! How did I miss that. Thank you it worked now!